# Ruby on Rails delay in updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails and I've come across a little quirk that I can't seem to find the answer to anywhere:

Since I'm learning rails, I'll make a few tweaks to the code while the localhost is running (rails s) and then just refresh the browser to see if the change I wanted to make was accurate. This works for changes to the views, css, html, routing, etc.

But now I'm making changes to a controller file that is calling another ruby class that I wrote and when I make changes to the ruby class, they don't show up right away. The way I know this is that I use a variety of printf functions in the Ruby class to show the current state of things and if I add one and re-run, it won't show unless I shut the server down and restart it.

Any thoughts? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must autoload the folder which contains your custom files:

```
# in config/application.rb:

# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

There you write the folder which you want to be autoloaded.

WARNING: the naming is very important: files in there must be named as the class/modules they define (like models, controllers, etc):

- foo.rb must define Foo costant
- foo/bar.rb must define Foo:Bar costant

and you cannot autoload files which do not have this naming convention. The reason is linked to the autoload working: when in your code call f.e. the `Foo` constant, and the constant is missing, Rails tries to see if in its autoload paths there is a file that follows this naming convention, and if there is it loads it.

Comment: So, my external ruby code is a file called "car.rb" and inside of it, I define a class called "Car" - I think that follows the naming convention needed. In addition to the class, the file also holds a def for a method I wrote that acts on the class. The changes I'm making are inside that method, but they aren't registering, even though I'm using "config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers)"

Comment: The file should not be in the controller folder, because Rails expects files in app/controllers to be controllers; I suggest you to make a new folder ( I usually use lib/#{app_name} ) and move the Car class into this new folder

Comment: This is going to sound super-noob, but I can't get it to load from lib. I've tried to just use [require 'car.rb'] and I get a load error. I've also tried a variety of paths like lib/car.rb and lib/assets/car.rb and none of them will load either.

Comment: ok, let's try to see the single steps:
(1) in config/application.rb: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/autoload)
(2) in lib/autoload: move car.rb here
(3) ensure in lib/autoload/car.rb there is module|class Car ... def my_method ... end

Comment: I've done everything above, but I'm still getting a Load Error - "Cannot load such file" in the controller where I call [require "lib/autoload/car.rb"]

Comment: you must not require it, it gets required automatically: if you remove the require it should work without other efforts -- Rails is able to require it automatically, when you use autoload + naming convention